# Mixing scss and less files in one project (bootstrap customization context)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, less

P.S. I do not have much knowledge and experience with gulp and worklfows on front end.
So the questions is: is it a normal gulp workflow:

- Load all bootstrap `scss` files from `node_modules` into project (`src` folder)
- In `src` rewrite variables (using `customvariables.scss`)
- Compile to `bootstrap.css`
- Move to `dist`
- Take into account that all other styles on page are written using less. Thus there would be less and scss (only for bootstrap) files
- Take into account that there is also second variables file (variables.less) where some items like colors are the same as in bootstrap variable.sass

Here is the description of my question:

- I am given existing project (front end only) that was not written by me
- It is written in bad style and I wish to fix it, for instance, there are too many different buttons with different styles; in general there are too many bootstrap style overrides that could be done by simple bootstrap customization (using bootstrap variables and some minor changes)
- One of the problems is that it references `bootstrap.css` (not `scss` and it is not loaded using `npm`, but it was simply added by hand).
- Custom styles in the whole project are written in `less`

I would like to customize bootstrap (changing default colors, adding default borders etc.), however, for this it would be better to use bootstrap-sass and change default values in variables. Afterwards I would have to compile (using gulp for instance) `sass` to `css` and include `bootstrap.css` into project.

This will result in `scss` and `less` in one project. Moreover I would probably need to have two variables version (like `variables.less` and `variables.sass`) where some values would be the same (like colors). I cannot rewrite everything to `scss` right now.

Comment: It's definitely doable. Not sure how you define "normal" though. Better to stick to one language.

Comment: Ok, if stick to one language, then how to use bootstrap? Bootstrap is written in scss and if you want to customize it you can do it only via scss. Otherwise it ends up rewriting half of classes like btn, btn-primary and so on.

Comment: Move the other code to Sass. Even if you can't do it right now, it's better in the long run.

Comment: I was planning to do this.